# Recurrence Relations for Password question

Tags: combinatorics

I'm having a problem with figuring out a recurrence relation for the following question:  Passwords are strings of upper case letters and can only contain even number of "X" with 0 being an even number.  Find recurrence relation for valid passwords of length n.

I figured out (or at least I think I did) gn for n = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 to see a pattern.  Here is what I have:

g0 = 1
g1 = 25
g2 = 1^2 + 25^2
g3 = 25^3 + 3(25)
g4 = 1^4 + 25^4 + 6(25^2)

I'm having a very difficult time figuring out the recursive rule for this pattern.  Any help would be appreciated!  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the kind of recurrence you want. Here is a first-order recurrence.

Let $a_n$ be the number of valid (even number of X) passwords of length $n$. Then the number of invalid ones (odd number of X) is $26^n-a_n$.

How do we make a valid password of length $n+1$? Either (i) append any non-X to a valid password of length $n$, or (ii) append an X to an invalid password of length $n$. Thus
$$a_{n+1}=25a_n +(26^n-a_n)=24a_n+26^n.$$